# Reverse of the logical operator AND (&)

Tags: logical-operators, boolean-logic

```
 a + b = c
 c - a = b
```

Ok, now

```
 a & b = c
 c ?? a = b
```

which operator replace "??" ?
Thanks

Comment: So now you know that `&` doesn't have an inverse operation. Now see if you can generalize the problem: do *any* of the logical operators have inverses?

Comment: Shame on me, I must use "Inverse" instead of "Reverse". Eric Lippert, your question is very important, why you don't post it?

Comment: I think he was suggesting it to you as an exercise. The short answer is "yes". If for any given a there are no two different values of b that map to the same c, then it has an inverse. The most famous example is probably XOR. The most trivial is a OP b = b.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no such operator, because it will be ill-defined if it exists:

so, let `a = 0, c = 0`

we have

```
a & 0 = c
a & 1 = c
```

then, we should have

```
c ?? a = 0   and  c ?? a = 1
```

, but an operator/function cannot return two values given the same input/parameters.

Answer (score 22):

It's impossible. This is because `a & b` is a lossy transformation.

You don't know whether any dropped `1` bits were part of `a` or `b`.

Comment: This is wrong. If you know `c` and `a` you can recover `b`.

Comment: @Paulpro: I disagree. E.g. if c and a are both zero, then b can be anything. Methinks I keep my job; for the time being.

Comment: @Paulpro: we'll publish jointly.

Comment: I've been thinking about this some more - it's an interesting question - and I came to the conclusion that having a lossy transformation for certain values might not be enough reason that there is no reverse operator. For instance, multiplication has a reverse, but it is lossy for one of the operands `== 0` (just like `&&`). I wonder if there is a three-valued logical operator `a ? b` where `0 ? .` is undefined (just like `0/0`) and `1 ? b` is `b`. I haven't been able to find one.

Answer (score 12):

You can't.

```
0 && 0 == 0
1 && 0 == 0
```

To reverse this, you'd need an operator that gives back both `0` and `1`.

(But if `b == 1` you do of course know that `a == c`.)

Answer (score 0):

No operator can replace "??" !
Only relation (logical relation !) b = (c=a)x2 + (not c)
can replace ""??".

J.Kawecki: Logical Relations. Warsaw,2019 Druk24h.pl

Comment: I think your post might benefit from using https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help And please make more obvious what the last line contributes to the answer. It looks like a post signature, which is not appreciated on StackOverflow. That is what your profile is for.